# C Programm to print full pyramid

Tags: c

I have this program to solve for a full pyramid.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int i, j, rows;
  printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
  scanf("%d", & rows);
  for (i = 1; i <= rows; ++i) {
    for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
      printf("%d ", j);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

the output is this

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

How can I print this like a full pyramid? Again from the left to print the same thing.

Desired output:

```
   1   1
  12   12
 123   123
1234   1234
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a full pyramid. Can you post an example of the desired output?

Comment: @JasonBakeri edited the post to the output that i want is there any way to post the picture of the output that i want?thank you

Comment: @JasonBaker i want to print again the same output but with space..like one triangle from the left with this numbers and one from the right just like the output

Answer (score 1):

I think your looking for something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int rowCount, numberCount, rows;

    printf("Enter the number of rows: \n>");
    scanf(" %d", &rows);

    for(rowCount = 1; rowCount <= rows; rowCount++) {

        for(numberCount = rowCount; numberCount < rows; numberCount++)
            printf(" ");

        for(numberCount = rowCount; numberCount >= 1; numberCount--)
            printf("%d",numberCount);

        printf("   ");

        for(numberCount = 1; numberCount <= rowCount; numberCount++)
            printf("%d",numberCount);

        printf("\n");
    }


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Did you saw the desired output?how can i post my desired output?i have the image for the output how can i upload the image here?it says that i can't post because my reputation is not less than ten....